# Re-Arrange rows in two-dimensional arrays without numpy

Tags: python, arrays, row

Rows in a 2D array are re-arranged according to the number of "*" in each row.

Example:

My array:

```
[['*', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
 ['*', '-', '-', '*', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '*', '*', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['*', '-', '*', '*', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*']]

Expected output:

[['*', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
 ['-', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
 ['*', '-', '*', '*', '-', '-'],
 ['*', '-', '-', '*', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '*', '*', '-', '-', '-']]
```

The row with the greatest number of `*` will be arranged first, while the row with the least number of `-` will be arranged last. If rows have the same amount of `*`, the relative ordering is maintained.

Comment: Since number of entries in inner list is constant, having greatest number of * will imply least number of -, So what do you mean by The row with the greatest number of * will be arranged first, while the row with the least number of - will be arranged last. They seem to be contradicting

Answer (score 1):

Sorting with an appropriate key function will do:

```
array = [['*', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
         ['*', '-', '-', '*', '-', '-'],
         ['-', '*', '*', '-', '-', '-'],
         ['*', '-', '*', '*', '-', '-'],
         ['-', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*']]

array.sort(key=lambda a: a.count('*'), reverse=True)
array
#[['*', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
# ['-', '-', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
# ['*', '-', '*', '*', '-', '-'],
# ['*', '-', '-', '*', '-', '-'],
# ['-', '*', '*', '-', '-', '-']]
```